# Changing base map in Ushahidi?

Tags: ushahidi

Fascinated by the idea of a 'crowd map' and 'citizen journalism', I've been perusing [Ushahidi](http://www.ushahidi.com) and it should serve me well. I would like to [emulate](http://brooklynsnowremoval2010.crowdmap.com/) it except for - the base map.

I would prefer a personal base map(s) served from Geoserver for instance and not the Google Map. I see OSM can also be used but it lacks the detail I require.

Any ideas on How-To or alternative projects?

[I've literally scrounged the web via Google search for answers without success. The Ushahidi forum has not been helpful as well]

Comment: have a look at http://geocommons.com/

Comment: I have recently installed Ushahidi to test it´s features and useability. I would also like to use my own geodata as basemaps, but found it not as straight forward as I thought. Did you manage to get the modifications working?

Comment: I managed to get geoserver wms layers working in ushahidi...well almost. They get displayed when I choose them in the map settings page, but when I view the website, there is a small problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ushahidi uses OpenLayers as its mapping technology. This means that it should be possible with minimal modifications to use any layer OpenLayers supports (like WMS from GeoServer) with minimal changes; look in the page you linked for Layer.Google, and replace it with a corresponding Layer.WMS.